# What is the difference between rebellion attempt and attempted rebellion?

Tags: attributive-nouns, deverbal-adjectives

I want to understand if there is any difference between "rebellion attempt" and "attempted rebellion". The first is a noun-noun while the second is an adjective noun. I think both are ok, but I do know if one is preferable to the other.

Also, to me both wordings carry the same meaning, is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're close enough in absolute meaning - the difference is one of tone. In each case, the emphasis falls on the second word.

If you were Counsel for the defence, "rebellion attempt" would be better as the emphasis would be on "attempt" (ie. nothing politically significant happened). Counsel for the prosecution would prefer "attempted rebellion", with the emphasis on "rebellion".